# Jasmine-jquery, testing generated GUI for (nested) directives

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-directive, jasmine-jquery

I recently started using jasmine-jquery (1.3.1) together with angular (1.0.6) and need an advice on testing GUI.
I have some view for controller, which has angular directives, like 'view.html':

```
<div id='main-div'>
  <div my-directive objects-to-iterate='someScopeObjects'>
   <span id='default-span'>some default text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

, and in JS a directive "myDirective" is defined, having template-by-url 'myDirective.html' which includes `ng-repeat` and makes some nested div (row) foreach in `objectsToIterate`.
I load fixtures for 'view.html' and 'myDirective.html'.
Now I would like to test that during user interaction there are really some elements (rows) in 'myDirective' repeated block.
Beginning was simple:

```js
var div = $('div#main-div');
div = $compile(div)(scope);
scope.$digest();
expect(div).toBeVisible();
```

And now I'm stuck. Cannot get access to "generated" source of 'myDirective' element. If I use

```js
div.find('whatever-selector-for-element-my-directive'),
```

I get

```
<div my-directive objects-to-iterate='someScopeObjects'>
   <span id='default-span'>some default text</span>
</div>
```

If I try to compile+digest this html against scope, I still get same markup. How could I get "generated" source, looking like (pseudo)

```
<div id='my-directive-content'>
  <div id='object-1'>blah</div>
  <div id='object-2'>blah</div>
</div>
```

in order to check if there are N rows visible to user?
`someScopeObjects` in scope exist and are valid.

And my next step is actually testing same thing for directives nested inside of 'my-directive', so I somehow have to get access to the scope of 'my-directive'. How? :)

Thank you.

Comment: my guess is that you might need to use scope.$apply() or scope.$digest() after compiling because there is an ng-repeat inside and you need angular to go all the way. if that's correct, I can elaborate more in a solution

Comment: Excuse me, my bad, I use it already, just forgot to mention. Will update the question.